# redis all keys are not migrating to cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I have created aws elasticache cluster with 3 nodes and 3 shards, I'm trying to migrate redis keys from my ec2 to cluster, but only 1/3 of keys are migrating, If I create a cluster with 2 nodes 1/2 keys are copying, I want o migrate all keys to aws elasticcache. How..?

Comment: It seems that you incorrectly configured the cluster. You should give more information.

Comment: How are you migrating them? Is it your script or an automated process?